# How can I construct one equation from R's multivariate splines regression?

Tags: r, model, spline, non-linear-regression, coefficients

I have a data set with five variables and a dependent (result). The data looks like this. I have about 400 rows.

```
Result        E       S       A       P       U
1  1.478 594.9285 20.1841 43.9135 -0.0137 26.6003
2  2.192 595.6935 19.3381 44.7695 -0.0029 24.3531
3  2.453 595.6147 18.5576 46.9487  0.0152 26.4588
4  2.560 596.2093 17.0476 36.1352  0.0345 25.0307
5  2.468 595.1657 13.7379 13.6506  0.0753 31.4033
6  2.365 596.8336 13.2268  9.2305  0.0828 24.9807
```

After some trials, I found a spline model with the variables A and S works the best. Based on the data distributions, I set these knots.

```
knotsS <- quantile(MasterFile1$S, p = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
knotsA <- quantile(MasterFile1$A, p = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))

SplinesModel <- lm(Result ~ bs(A, knots=knotsA) + bs(S, knots=knotsS), data = Data)
summary(SplinesModel)
```

And I can see this result.

```
Call:
lm(formula = Result ~ bs(A, knots = knotsA) + bs(S, knots = knotsS), 
    data = Data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.57666 -0.29348  0.05863  0.29638  1.24709 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             1.44576    0.33359   4.334 1.87e-05 ***
bs(A, knots = knotsA)1  1.75803    0.40137   4.380 1.53e-05 ***
bs(A, knots = knotsA)2 -0.41603    0.19005  -2.189  0.02918 *  
bs(A, knots = knotsA)3  1.13906    0.18650   6.107 2.46e-09 ***
bs(A, knots = knotsA)4 -0.70872    0.38614  -1.835  0.06721 .  
bs(A, knots = knotsA)5  0.06699    0.39630   0.169  0.86585    
bs(A, knots = knotsA)6  0.08684    0.20015   0.434  0.66461    
bs(S, knots = knotsS)1  0.37046    0.43912   0.844  0.39938    
bs(S, knots = knotsS)2  0.87102    0.29510   2.952  0.00335 ** 
bs(S, knots = knotsS)3 -0.55736    0.39260  -1.420  0.15651    
bs(S, knots = knotsS)4  0.87541    0.36134   2.423  0.01586 *  
bs(S, knots = knotsS)5  0.16582    0.33568   0.494  0.62160    
bs(S, knots = knotsS)6  0.28792    0.35590   0.809  0.41901    

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4724 on 389 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.451, Adjusted R-squared:  0.434 
F-statistic: 26.63 on 12 and 389 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I would like to create one regression equation from these coefficients. I saw some tutorials explaining how to use spline knots and coefficients to create an equation for a one variable model, but not for multivariate. Is it even possible?

Comment: 6 of the coefficients are not significant. I wonder if fm <- lm(Result ~ A + S, Data) would be sufficient? What does `anova(SplineModel, fm)` give?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried lm and here is the output: Res.Df 1. 389, 2. 399, RSS 1. 86.792, 2. 130.286, DF -10, Sum of Sq -43.493, F 19.494, Pr(>F) < 2.2e-16 ***

Comment: The full lmodel is significantly different so it cannot be simplified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try other method, maybe MARS.